# Use dynamic parameters in Angular Resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, angularjs-resource

the Angular-Resource documentation says for parameters:

> If any of the parameter value is a function, it will be executed every time when a param value needs to be obtained for a request (unless the param was overridden).

Unfortunately this does not work for me, the function is only called once when the resource is initialized.

My case: 
I have a global Application state which you can choose on the top navigation of the app. This state affects a query param in most calls. (e.g. the date for which the call is valid). I maintain this global state in a service.

My Services (model layer) look like this:

```
function($resource, ApplicationState) {
      return $resource('test/:_id', {
        date: ApplicationState.getCurrentTime()
      }, {
        get: {
          method: 'GET'
        }
      });
    }
```

I'd expect `ApplicationState.getCurrentTime()` to be called on every get call. It is only called once.

I created a plunkr as an example. Open the Browsers Debug Console to see that `ApplicationState.getCurrentTime()` is only called once and not every time you click on the button.

http://plnkr.co/edit/qeoIUuzFCqnQNdnYp5ZX?p=preview

What do I do wrong? Is there a better way to inject dynamic parameters to some resources? I know the concept of request intereceptors, but I need this only on some services and not all.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I opened a bug report to the angular team to find out if it is a bug or a missunderstanding of the documentation: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10803

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer with the help of **frfancha** on Github, the trick is to pass the function itself and not the result of the function.

See the missing brackets after ApplicationState.getCurrentTime here:

```
function($resource, ApplicationState) {
  return $resource('test/:_id', {
    date: ApplicationState.getCurrentTime
  }, {
    get: {
      method: 'GET'
    }
  });
}
```

The function is now evaluated every time a request is made.

An updated Plnkr can be found here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Qx9HSsFwt5LDiM6Vmgff?p=preview
Credits go to [frfrancha](https://github.com/frfancha) on Github